# res.render is not rendering page and there is no error

Tags: node.js, express

Hi I have tried several times this and no result so far, I have this code

```
router.post('/deleteItem',(req,res) => {
  res.render('menu', {pageTitle:'Menu', navBarOn:'1', userLevel:req.user.userLevel, userName:req.user.fname, userLname:req.user.lname, items})
})
```

The request is sent but the page is not rendering. I tried surrounding it by a try catch block, adding console.logs to see that they go thru but there is nothing. The odd part is that I have several other routers that have the same or similar paths and they do load. Is it because is a post? because I also have another post and at the end render the new page

```
router.post('/menu', (req, res,) => {
    const {menuItem, description, price, id_cat} = req.body
    let errors = []

    if(id_cat == 0){
        errors.push({msg: "Please select a valid category!"})
    }
    if(errors.length>0){
        res.render('menu',{
            errors,
            errorsL:'1',
            menuItem,
            description,
            price,
            pageTitle:"Menu",
            navBarOn:'1',
            userLevel:req.user.userLevel,
            userName:req.user.fname,
            userLname:req.user.lname
        })
    } else{
        MenuItem.findOne({menuItem:menuItem}).then(item => {
            if(item){
                errors.push({msg: "This item already exists!"})
                res.render('menu',{
                    errors,
                    errorsL:'1',
                    menuItem,
                    description,
                    price,
                    pageTitle:"Menu",
                    navBarOn:'1',
                    userLevel:req.user.userLevel,
                    userName:req.user.fname,
                    userLname:req.user.lname
                })
            }else{
                const newItem = new MenuItem ({
                    menuItem,
                    description,
                    price,
                    id_cat
                })
                newItem.save().then(menuItem =>{
                    req.flash(
                        'success_msg',
                        'The item has been added to the menu'
                    )
                    let items = []
                    MenuItem.find({is_active:1}).then(item => {
                        items = item
                        res.render('menu', {pageTitle:'Menu', navBarOn:'1', userLevel:req.user.userLevel, userName:req.user.fname, userLname:req.user.lname, items})
                    })
                })
            }
        })
    }

})

what am i doing wrong?
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a workaround on this. Before I have been using a fetch from the EJS which sent the info but somehow didn't execute the `res.render`. I got rid of the fetch and instead I'm using a phantomForm with hidden inputs and I have linked the button to this form. This managed to work pretty well.